# Laravel Form - Blank Fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have a form on Laravel which needs to be filled in by a user. But all of the fields of the form do not need to be filled in. They can be left blank. However as soon as a field is left blank, everything below that is left blank, even if they filled something in further down the form.

I basically would like it so that it only sends what the users fills in.

Comment: So basically everything after the first blank field should be ignored / not saved?

Comment: Basically they fill the form in and it is emailed over in table form. Now not all fields are required. They can be left blank. But when you miss say an input out the following inputs below are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right, so give me a try: you need to tell the validator, which fields are required by adding the corresponding rule.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('name' => 'Dayle'),
    array('name' => 'required|min:5')
);
```

If fields are not being required, simply don't specify the rule, and they are optional by default.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('name' => 'Dayle'),
    array('name' => 'min:5') // note that 'required' is missing here!
);
```

In case the validation fails never the less, you may redirect back and providing the input, previously typed in by the user.

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput();
}
```

This wasy, the fields are automatically being populated with the given input. You might want to have a look at the laracasts-episodes on [validation](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/12) and [forms](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/10) for further reference. They are really good.

Comment: Is there a validation rule that I can set so that it does not matter if the input is filled in or not. As I want it so that if it is filled in then the validation is saved with input and then if it is left blank, then its ignored.

Comment: yeah, just take away 'required', its the default behaviour, just as i wrote in the middle, or am i getting you wrong?

Comment: I will give it a try. And see how I get on. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Okay, I have a new issue. I want to email the form as a table. But not all fields are required. The user can leave them blank. How would I get them to not show the blank fields, only the ones that are filled in on the form please.

Comment: well, that is another question. i personally would not care about this in a view as it is not a presentation issue. so the approach would be to just submit all the stuff of the form stuff and filter it within your controller method. Another possibility would be to take care of that on the client-side (within the view) using js, but in my opinion, this is not a very clean solution. But this doen't really belong to your question, right? maybe, there are other ways so you migth want to ask another question or look if one already exists..

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right.
This is how you can remove all input values after the first blank:

```
$input = Input::all();
$firstBlank = array_search('', $input);
if($firstBlank === false){
    $firstBlankIndex = array_search($firstBlank, array_keys($input));
    $input = array_slice($input, 0, $firstBlankIndex, true);
}

// use $input
```